# resolve controller variable on directive param without binding for templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, binding

This directive is somewhere outside of our different app frontends and will be called with custom templateUrl's for different usecases.

```
Module.directive 'directiveName', ->
  templateUrl: (tElement, tAttrs) ->
    tAttrs.templateurl || 'default.html'
...
```

In some new frontend we went for webpack.
Our old bower/gulp/npm/sprockets setup allowed us to just use the directive like

```
<directive-name templateUrl="./_custom.html" ... />
```

But this doesn't work for webpack since the partials have to be required first and the directive isn't supposed to know anything about it. So I went for a template loader to get the path of the partial assigned to a controller variable and called on the directive attribute.

```
@templateUrl = require('ngtemplate!html!./custom.html')
```

So the obvious directive call would be

```
<directive-name templateUrl="ctrl.templateUrl" ... />
# or
<directive-name templateUrl="{{ctrl.templateUrl}}" ... />
```

But the value doesn't get evaluated. So the only thing that gets to the directive is literally `ctrl.templateUrl` or `{{ctrl.templateUrl}}`.
Binding it to the scope is not an option since its not availabe on the time of resolving the templateUrl in the directive.

Edit: Just as an addition
using ng-attr to get the controller variable evaluted first like

```
<directive-name ng-attr-templateUrl="{{ctrl.templateUrl}}" ... />
```

Doesn't work.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: _"So I went for a template loader to get the path of the partial inside of the controller."_  You need  the path inside the `templateUrl` function, but get it inside the controller. What's the logic behind this?

Comment: @zeroflagL I could just add it to the directive like `<directive-name templateUrl="require('ngtemplate!html!./custom.html')" ... />` But thats hardly to read so I assign it to a controller variable that belongs to the view where the directive is called.

Comment: You can leave the HTML exactly the same and call require inside the `templateUrl` function. Any objections?

Comment: @zeroflagL yes because the partial that is used will be assigned via the attribute. Since the directive isn't supposed to know anything about it. If its empty it used some default. Its some generic directive that has different use cases and the view partial therefore changes where it is implemented. And `require("ngtemplate!html!#{tAttrs.templateurl}")` inside `templateUrl()` wont work since its its still literally `ctrl.templateUrl`.

Comment: So the directive must not know that webpack is being used? That's an important piece of information that completely changes the context of your question.

Comment: @zeroflagL well yes, I hoped its clear by mentioning how we used the directive in the legacy part. I guess I have to rephrase that

Answer (score 0):

`templateUrl` functions do not have access to the scope of the directive which is why the value will not be evaluated. You can pass the variable in to the directive and then compile the contents of the file into the element:

http://plnkr.co/edit/36BhCaadkLWyrNjkjCEc?p=preview

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('directiveName', function($http, $compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      templateurl: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      $http.get(scope.templateurl || './default.html').then(function(results) {
        elem.html(results.data);
        $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  }
})
.controller('controllerName', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.templateUrl = "./_custom.html";
});
```